# Python int to hex in while loop

Tags: python

```
number = 240

while (number < 257):
    data = format(number, 'x')
    data_hex = data.decode("hex")
    number = number + 1
```

Error message:

```
    data_hex = data.decode("hex")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
    output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
TypeError: Odd-length string
```

How can I make a while loop good, than no put error?

Comment: You didn't include the error. Also, if you wanted to have the character, it's much easier to use `chr(number)`.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to accomplish? The trivial solutions to preventing errors in your sample are unlikely to solve your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking this one step too far; `number = 256` fails here:

```
>>> format(256, 'x')
'100'
>>> format(256, 'x').decode('hex')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
    output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
TypeError: Odd-length string
```

That's because the `hex` encoding can only handle *two character hex values*; you'd have to 0-pad that number:

```
>>> format(256, '04x').decode('hex')
'\x01\x00'
```

or limit your loop to not produce 256:

```
while number < 256:
```

It is much easier to use the [`chr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) rather than go through formatting the number as hex then decoding:

```
data_hex = chr(number)
```

Demo:

```
>>> format(255, 'x').decode('hex')
'\xff'
>>> chr(255)
'\xff'
```

Provided `number` stays below 255, of course.